# Unable to change git config user.name when amending/squashing

Tags: git

I'm using git under ubuntu

```
administrator@ubuntu:/host/Sites/CitySpade$ git add .
administrator@ubuntu:/host/Sites/CitySpade$ git commit --amend -m "Facebook Authentication, failed at sandbox mode"
[zhenkun 0d8391b] Facebook Authentication, failed at sandbox mode
 Author: Administrator <administrator@ubuntu.ubuntu-domain>
 10 files changed, 88 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
 create mode 100644 db/migrate/20140113092541_add_omniauth_to_accounts.rb
administrator@ubuntu:/host/Sites/CitySpade$ git config user.name
cqcn1991
administrator@ubuntu:/host/Sites/CitySpade$ git config --global user.name
cqcn1991
```

However, when I make a new commit:

```
administrator@ubuntu:/host/Sites/CitySpade$ git add .
administrator@ubuntu:/host/Sites/CitySpade$ git commit -m "try username"
[zhenkun 295514b] try username
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
administrator@ubuntu:/host/Sites/CitySpade$ git log
commit 295514b44aa72033999028f381c2f2ea2fc58753
Author: cqcn1991 <cqcn1991@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 14 10:16:35 2014 +0800
```

And there is no environment variable like `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` or `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`

UPDATE:
When I use git rebase -i HEAD, I also end up with `adminstrator` as username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`git commit --amend` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

> **The new commit has the same parents and author as the current one (the `--reset-author` option can countermand this).**

(Rebase also attempts to preserve author information.  You can have rebase stop for editing, and then use `git commit --amend --reset-author`, to alter this in an interactive rebase.)

Comment: I finally get around with it using `git commit --amend --reset-author`